# Validate a booking form with more than one user record

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, dom

I need to validate my form using jQuery or JavaScript when the page is submitted.

The conditions to validate my form are:

- Name, age, and email of first passenger is compulsory.
- If user enters additional names of any 2 to 10 passengers list then it should be mandatory to add age and email IDs of additional passengers.
- Email IDs of all passengers should be unique and valid.
- The user should agree to the terms and conditions.

Here's my HTML.

```html
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn1" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag1" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em1" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn2" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag2" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em2" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn3" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag3" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em3" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn4" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag4" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em4" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn5" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag5" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em5" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn6" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag6" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em6" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn7" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag7" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em7" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn8" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag8" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em8" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn9" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag9" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em9" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn10" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag10" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em10" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>

        <input type="checkbox" value="Agree to our terms and agreement" />

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

```js
if ($('#fn1').val() == ""{
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#fn1').focus();
    return
    }


if ($('#fn1').val() != "" && ($('#ag1').val() == "" || !emailpattern.test($('#em1').val()))) {
   event.preventDefault(); 
  $('#fn1').focus();
    return
}
```

I did this individually for every passenger. I have no code to check unique email IDs.

Comment: show what you have tried.

Comment: if ($('#fn1').val() != "" && ($('#ag1').val() == "" || !emailpattern.test($('#em1').val()))) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

Did this individually for every passenger, and no code still to check unique email ID

Comment: edit question and add it. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32033105/edit

Comment: Hello Nikhil, thanks for using StackOverflow.  We can help you solve an error but not write your code.  If you have a specific question, please specify it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can restate the four requirements as follows:

- At least one name must be entered.
- For each name that has been entered, the age and email address must be specified.
- There must be a unique email address for each name.
- The "terms and conditions" checkbox must be checked.

The snippet below validates all of these requirements. Note the following.

- The HTML contains a single entry which is duplicated when the page loads. The global variable `numEntries` specifies the desired number of entries in the form.
- We use `entryCount` to keep track of how many names have been entered into the form.
- A hash is used to store the name corresponding to each email address. We look up each new email address in this hash to see if a name has already been assigned.

```js
var numEntries = 10;

// Remove whitespace from beginning and end of string.
function strip(s) {
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}

window.onload = function () {
  // Make ten entries and store them in an array.
  var form = document.getElementById('entryForm'),
      entry = form.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
      nextSibling = entry.nextSibling,
      entries = [entry];
  for (var i = 1; i < numEntries; ++i) {
    var newEntry = entry.cloneNode(true);
    form.insertBefore(newEntry, nextSibling);
    entries.push(newEntry);
    entry = newEntry;
  }
  // Make it easy to look up field values for each entry.
  entries.forEach(function (entry) {
    ['name', 'age', 'email', 'phone'].forEach(function (field) {
      entry[field] = entry.getElementsByClassName(field)[0];
    });
  });
  // Attach a validation function to the form submission button.
  document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = function () {
    if (!document.getElementById('agreementBox').checked) {
      alert('Error: you must agree to our terms and conditions.');
      return;
    }
    var entryCount = 0,
        emailHash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < numEntries; ++i) {
      var entry = entries[i],
          name = strip(entry.name.value);
      if (strip(entry.name.value) !== '') {
        var age = strip(entry.age.value),
            email = strip(entry.email.value);
        if (age === '' || email === '') {
          alert('Error: you must enter the age and email address of ' + name + '.');
          return;
        }
        if (emailHash[email] !== undefined) {
          alert('Error: ' + name + ' has the same email address as ' +
                emailHash[email] + '. Addresses must be unique.');
          return;
        }
        emailHash[email] = name;
        ++entryCount;
      }
    }
    if (entryCount == 0) {
      alert('Error: you must enter at least one name.');
      return;
    }
    alert('Success! The form has been validated.');
  };
};
```

```css
.agreement {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<form id="entryForm">
  <div>
    <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" />
    <input class="age" type="number" placeholder="Age" />
    <select>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
    <input class="phone" type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
  </div>
  
  <p class="agreement">
    <input id="agreementBox" type="checkbox"> Agree to our terms and conditions
  </p>

  <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Below is a version that uses exactly the HTML you posted in your question.

```js
// Remove whitespace from beginning and end of string.
function strip(s) {
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}

window.onload = function () {
  // Find the entry input areas and store them in an array.
  var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
  var entries = form.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
    var entry = entries[i],
        inputs = entry.getElementsByTagName('input');
    // Make it easy to look up field values for each entry.
    ['name', 'age', 'email', 'phone'].forEach(function (field, ix) {
      entry[field] = inputs[ix];
    });
  }
  // Attach a validation function to the form submission button.
  var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input'),
      agreementBox = inputs[inputs.length - 2],
      submitButton = inputs[inputs.length - 1];
  submitButton.onclick = function () {
    if (!agreementBox.checked) {
      alert('Error: you must agree to our terms and conditions.');
      return;
    }
    var entryCount = 0,
        emailHash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
      var entry = entries[i],
          name = strip(entry.name.value);
      if (strip(entry.name.value) !== '') {
        var age = strip(entry.age.value),
            email = strip(entry.email.value);
        if (age === '' || email === '') {
          alert('Error: you must enter the age and email address of ' + name + '.');
          return;
        }
        if (emailHash[email] !== undefined) {
          alert('Error: ' + name + ' has the same email address as ' +
                emailHash[email] + '. Addresses must be unique.');
          return;
        }
        emailHash[email] = name;
        ++entryCount;
      }
    }
    if (entryCount == 0) {
      alert('Error: you must enter at least one name.');
      return;
    }
    alert('Success! The form has been validated.');
  };
};
```

```css
form {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn1" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag1" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em1" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn2" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag2" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em2" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn3" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag3" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em3" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn4" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag4" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em4" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn5" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag5" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em5" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn6" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag6" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em6" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn7" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag7" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em7" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn8" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag8" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em8" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn9" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag9" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em9" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fn10" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="number" id="ag10" placeholder="Age" />
            <select><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select>
            <input type="email" id="em10" placeholder="E-mail" />
            <input type="number" placeholder="Mobile" />
        </div>

        <input type="checkbox" value="Agree to our terms and agreement" />

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but this code doesn't solves my issue. You are duplicating the form div element.. but I cannot do so. I use asp.net for development. I have to differentiate each element (input-box) with unique id attribute. the design of the page will remain same as in my question and is fixed.

Comment: If you insist on using exactly that HTML, see the second snippet that I've added to my question.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. You now have enough reputation to upvote it, too.

Comment: You can also upvote my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058248/